# The specified principle is not known in the authentication system

Tags: java, c#, kerberos, gssapi, sspi

I have a C# client based on SSPI and Java server based on GSSAPI. The flow communication flow is as below.

> 1. Client creates TGT
> 2. Client passes TGT to server
> 3. Server uses the TGT and generates server token
> 4. Server passes the server token to client
> 5. Client uses that server token and generates the SGT

My communication flow breaks from the 6th step.

> SSPI client failed to validate the server token with the error "Failed
>   to invoke InitializeSecurityContext for a client. The specified
>   principle is not known in the authentication system."

Seems like the SPN use in Java side can not be recognized by the C# SSPI. According to [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380496(v=vs.85).aspx) there is a windows compatible SPN name format. My spn which is used in Java side is as below.

> HTTP/myserver-domain.com@test.local where test.local is the realm
>   name. Any suggestion would be a great help.

Thanks

Comment: The desribed flow is incorrect. It does not work like that. The client does not create a TGT, the system does. The client doesn't send the TGT, it sends a service ticket. Rather than describing technical steps, describe what you want to achieve. It will be easier to give you an advice.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I could resolve the problem. The SPN which I used for the server was not windows compatible. Once I change it I could solve the problem. Regarding the steps, before sending the service ticket, first the client sends client token to the server asking the server to identify client right? I referred this client token as the TGT.

Comment: Not exactly, the client sends the service ticket to the target server and may ask the server to authenticate too (mutual auth). The client token is *not* the TGT. Sharing the TGT is dangerous because you reveal your identity for 10 hours.